# Maintain value after Postback using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select list

```
<select id="type" name="type" onchange="type_Change(this.id)">
```

and i want to maintain selected value after the postback.
how will i acheive through jquery.
please anyone???

Comment: After post back rebind the drop down with the selected value.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the selected value of select through javascript/jQuery code then you can store the changed selected value in some hidden field and later using it in code behind.

*Html*

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnForSelect" />
```

*Javascript*

```
function type_Change(idOfSelect)
{
      //your code
      document.getElementById('%= hdnForSelect.ClientID %>').value = "changed value";     
}
```

*Code behind*

```
string changedValue = hdnForSelect.Value;
```